# Разделение строки на подстроки

Tags: python

Вопрос новичка в пайтон. Я решал несколько разных задач, и часто у меня была необходимость разделить строку, на две подстроки в определенном моменте. Например, если у меня в строке есть ненужный элемент, и я могу его найти с помощью S.rfind(str, [start],[end]), то эту подстроку можно заменить с помощью замены шаблона, а как быть если у меня есть к примеру строка состоящая из десятичной дроби "21.4876" и я хочу отделить целые числа от десятичных, и записать их как две разные строки : "21" and "4876"

```
a = 21.4876
if a == int:
    print(a)
else:
    a = str(a)
    a = a[0 : a.rfind(".")] + a[a.rfind(".") + 1:len(a)+1]
print(a)
```

Я использовал такой код. Но я бы хотел узнать, какие еще есть способы, более проще ,чтобы удалить точку из десятичной дроби.

Comment: `a, b = "21.4876".split(".")`

Comment: `if a == int:` - даже если `a = 5`, то это всё равно будет `False`.